# Error to connect to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am a beginner in php, and for a project I want to connect me with my database but the problem is :

I need 4 variables:

```
$serveurname
$username
$password
$databasename
```

When i do :

```
$link = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password)
```

There are two errors :

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php on line 21

and

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php on line 21

I think the problem is : serveurname information is bad but I don't know where can I find it on phpmyadmin?

On phpmyadmin i see :

```
MySQL
Serveur: info-arie.iut.bx1 via TCP/IP
Version du serveur: 5.5.43-0+deb7u1
Version du protocole: 10
Utilisateur: dfrances@info-morgane.iut.bx1
Jeu de caractères pour MySQL: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

but information (at right of the screen on phpmyadmin) seems bad because in my code I have :

```
$servername = "info-arie.iut.bx1"; 
$username = "dfrances@info-morgane.iut.bx1";
```

Comment: $servername should probably be `localhost` user name will not be the same as phpmyadmin, have you set up  a user?

Comment: It is my university who have created this space. why localhost? and where can i find my user if it is not this username? is it my username for connection to the space?

Comment: then ask them.. how would we know how they have set it up

Comment: I can't find information on phpmyadmin interface?
We have just received a mail with id and password, so i imagine we can use it just with informations that we can see

Answer (score 1):

You can find phpmyadmin mysql connection info in file `config.inc.php` inside the phpmyadmin folder. Find entries like the following and use it for your code.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'someuser';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'somepass';
```

Comment: thanks a lot but where is this file? On the interface?

Comment: @Dam'sFrances It's on the phpmyadmin folder which I guess you don't have access to?

Comment: I am on Windows, maybe I forgot something? A special installation of phpmyadmin? I don't know? An idea to have this folder? :)

Comment: I have access to anything, just the access to interface phpmyadmin. Maybe I should create my own space.. Is it free?

Comment: You should clearly state your situation in your question, so we could answer correctly.

Comment: I think my universty have do thinks bad, so I am downloading mysql installer now. I have seen localhost somewhere so I think it will be good ;)

I wait the end and I test it

Comment: It is strange we can't create a new database with mySQL workbench?

Comment: I think you should focus on your initial problem, using mysqlworkbench might add another problem -- you will get confused. So, please state your situation clearly (edit your question for this).

Answer (score 1):

From your error message, the host where you run your PHP script cannot contact the database server.

Comment: My answer was edited (from "DNS" to "database") but I really meant the DNS server.